# Is it possible to use a quantifier on a non-capturing group ? - regex

Tags: java, regex

I catch a group by *regex* and I would like to catch
everything but not the group(s).
So group can have several occurences, on different locations, in the String.

My first thought was, to solve it with negativ lookahead but I failed with it. Therefore I tried it with non capturing group and I stuck here too.

> (bar) (baz) foo

I want foo.

This is what I have so far:

```
String input = "(bar) (baz) foo";


String matchesGroup = "((?=\\().*?\\))"; //matches (...)

// as Casimir et Hippolyte commented, I know use 
// ((?:(...))+) for the non capturing group

String matchesFoo = "((?:"+ matchesGroup +")+)\\s(.*)";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(matchesFoo);  
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

while (matcher.find()){
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

but there is nothing captured at all

> actual :
>
> expected : foo

Where is my fault in the regex ?

Comment: You need to repeat the non-capturing group, not `(match)`. Put the whitespace character class in the non-capturing group.

Comment: Well, you don't tell it to expect spaces between occurrences of 'matches'. The string `matchesmatches foo` works instead of your second example.

Comment: So you want everything of the input string that is not in within an opening and closing bracket?

Comment: [See this demo](http://ideone.com/M4HZI8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you want to match multiple (...) groups, account for the possible trailing space and move the `+` to quantify one or more of those (I moved the space into the group, and the `+` quantifying that whole structure)

```
String matchesFoo = "(?:(?:(?=\\().*?\\))\\s?)+(.*)";
```

[demo here](https://regex101.com/r/iH2rF1/3)

Comment: It can be made twice as efficient if lookarounds are replaced with a consuming pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try this:

```
String testtring = "matches matches foo";
testString = testString.replaceAll("matches", "");
System.out.println(testString);
```

Comment: i tried it before, but i want to work with groups, since I need
them afterwards